# Bash - Remove leading zero for numbers with double digits

Tags: bash, shell, leading-zero

I have a variable in bash number which contains values `01, 02, 03, 04, 05, 06, 07, 08, 09, 010, 011, 012.`

I would like to remove the leading zeros before `010, 011` and `012`. I only want to remove the leading zeroes if the number is a double digit number.

How can I achieve this?

Thanks in advance!

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Try:

```
a="012"
printf '%02d\n' "$((10#${a}))"
12
```

Comment: Hi @Eugeniu, I am getting the end result as 10 not 12 when a="012".

Comment: I'd tend to suggest quotes on the expansion -- granted, only a madman puts digits in IFS, but if such a madman *were* to run your code, it would behave unexpectedly as-is. :)

Comment: `printf '%02d\n' "$((10#${a}))"`, merging your two approaches, might be a more complete solution, since the OP "only want[s] to remove the leading zeroes if the number is [...] double digit".

Comment: @CharlesDuffy doing my edits while riding my bicycle. I will be more careful next time!

Answer (score 0):

Another way:

```
a="014"
printf "%02d\n" $(echo "obase=10;$a" |bc)
14
```

another one:

```
[[ $a =~ ^0+[1-9]{2,}$ ]] && a="$(echo $((10#${a})))"
echo $a
```

This one will remove all `0`s from beginning for `2` or more non-zero digit numbers.